# why the kubernetes liveness probe did not restart the pod

Tags: kubernetes

I want to check the process running or not in pod to make sure the health status, when the process not exists, the app is down, need to restart the pod. I am doing this job in kubneretes `v1.26` like this right now:

```
     livenessProbe:
            exec:
              command:
                - /bin/bash
                - '-c'
                - ps aux|grep "./rss-sync consume"|grep -v grep
            initialDelaySeconds: 190
            timeoutSeconds: 30
            periodSeconds: 30
            successThreshold: 1
            failureThreshold: 3
```

it seems did not work. when the process did not exists, the pods are not restart. the command output from pod like this:

```
/app # ps aux|grep "./rss-sync consume"|grep -v grep
/app #
```

Am I missing something? what should I do to let the pod restart when process exists?